# ETL : extraction from excel

Tags: pentaho, business-intelligence, talend

I'm trying to create a Pentaho Data Integration transformation which import data from an excel file, but Pentaho doesn't support files with so many rows. It can import data just from a file with 20000 rows. I think because it's an open source technology.

I want to find a solution, or replace Pentaho with another business intelligence technology from your suggestions.

Comment: It's not true. PDI can read as many data as you have. There is no limitation. Excel files are limited to 65536 rows, so that is your limit.
Perhaps you do something wrong!?

Comment: SO is not for suggesting other technologies. There are other sites for that. I've had memory issues with using large XLSX. Maybe you should convert to XLS or CSV first?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract data from large fils excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34254033/extract-data-from-large-fils-excel)

Answer (score 0):

Pentaho and Talend are both rock-solid ETL and data integration tools. If anything, their being open source is an incentive to use and strength .

You can easily read more than 20k rows from excel, using either tool. If the job encounters memory issues, consider increasing the memory allocated to the job. Talend's default setting is 1MB of memory.

One Talend job I worked on recently reads an excel File (XLSX) which often contains more than 80k rows in one tab.