# Extract data from large files excel

Tags: kettle, pdi

I'm using Pentaho Data Integration to create a transformation from xlsx files to mysql, but I can't import data from large files with `Excel 2007 xlsx(apache POI Straiming)`. It gives me out of memory errors.

Comment: I'd recommend converting XLSX to CSV first. Split the CSV into 10K records-ish. Import one CSV file at a time. If that causes issues, split CSVs to 1000 records and try again. I'd recommend starting that route first.

Comment: I have been successful with XLS files, when POI streaming crashes with XLSX files.

Comment: While accessing large files, Pentaho seems to run out of memory. You need to increase the size of the java memory by increasing the value of -Xmx by editing the spoon.bat or spoon.sh file. Check this [blog](https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/2014/11/27/memory-handling-in-pentaho-data-integration/)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this option ?

Advanced settings -> Generation mode -> Less memory consumed for large excel(Event mode

(You need to check "Read excel2007 file format" first)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to increase  jvm memory allocation before running the transformation. By default, pentaho data integration aka kettle comes with low memory allocation which would cause issues with running ETLs involving large files. You would need to modify the `-Xmx` value so that it specifies a larger upper memory limit in spoon.bat accordingly.

If you are using spoon in windows and edit spoon.bat in the line show below.

```
if "%PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS%"=="" set PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx512m" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
```

If you are using kitchen or pan, edit in those pan.bat or kitchen.bat accordingly. If you are using in linux, change in .sh files.